# Filter array - remove values that are present in another array

Tags: javascript

I have this array
`$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats` and there's an other array `$scope.flatsArray`

I want to remove values from `$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats` that are present in `$scope.flatsArray`.

I have done this:

```
$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats = $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.filter(function(f){
    return !$scope.someObj.flatsArray.some(function(v){
                return v.indexOf(f) >= 0;
    })
})
```

But I get an error saying v.indexOf is not a function

Comment: you should `console.log(v)` to check what you are getting there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v` in `flatsArray.some` callback function returns a single item rather than an array of items. So rather than checking for the index of, you can simply compare the values directly.

You need to

```
$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats = $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.filter(function(f){
    return !$scope.someObj.flatsArray.some(function(v){
                return v == f;
    })
})
```

Comment: ooops..i totally forgot

Comment: A fully qualified `===` should always be used unless you specifically intend for a loose match to be made (and then documented as such)

Answer (score 0):

Pick either `some` or `indexOf`. For example

```
$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats = $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.filter(function(f){
    return $scope.someObj.flatsArray.indexOf(f) === -1
})
```

or

```
$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats = $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.filter(function(f){
    return !$scope.someObj.flatsArray.some(function(item) { return item === f; })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to post the arrays so they can be used in answers, however, you could do this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats; i++) {
    var index = $scope.flatsArray.indexOf($scope.userEventData.selectedFlats[i]);
    if ( index > -1 ) {
        $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.splice(index, 1);
    } 
}
```

This will loop through each item in the **selectFlats** array and find the index of that item in the **flatsArray**, then remove that item from if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats = $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.filter(
    function(item) {
        return !($scope.someObj.flatsArray.contains(item))
    }
```